# How to access related record in CakePHP with mysql?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a database of two tables. One with blog posts and one with users, related by a user_id field in the post table. On my index page I have a table of the posts and I want to add the author to that however I want to display the user's name rather than their ID. I am trying to add an author field to my post objects like this in PostsController:

```
public function index() {
    $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
    foreach ($this as $post){
        $post['Post']['author'] = $this->User->findById($post['Post']['user_id']);
    }
}
```

however this brings the error that I am calling findById on null. I am very new to php so I think my understanding of how to use the loop may be incorrect. Perhaps there is a better way which does not require the loop?

Comment: I don't see you calling `$this->loadModel('User');` to make `$this->User` available. Are you doing that somewhere else?

Comment: oops yes I have added that now, I now get the error "Cannot use string offset as an array" on the line in the foreach

Answer (score 0):

Controllers in CakePHP, by default, only load their own models. If you need an additional model at some point, you need to [load it in manually](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#loading-additional-models).

That won't solve your problem though, because you're setting the result for the `find()` action straight into the view. You'll want to wait with that until you add the users to it. Oh, and you usually can't iterate through `$this` with `foreach`, unless your class implements an `Iterator`-like interface (which controllers should never have a reason to do)

```
public function index() {
    // first load in the User model
    $this->loadModel('User');

    // store the posts in a local variable first
    $posts = $this->Post->find('all');

    // loop through the local variable, also keep the index so we can reference
    // the post we're modifying
    foreach ($posts as $index => $post) {
        $post['Post']['author'] = $this->User->findById($post['Post']['user_id']);

        // write the modified $post back into the $posts array
        $posts[$index] = $post;
    }

    // **now** you can make $posts available to your view
    $this->set('posts', $posts);
}
```

Once you have this sorted out, [read up on linking models together](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html). There's a way to set up your `Post` model so that it will automatically fill `$post['Post']['author']` with the corresponding `User`, without you having to do that manually.

Answer (score 0):

Better you specify the relation in model.

In Post Model initialize the relation between post and user

```
public $hasOne = 'User';
```

Now in controller use Contain() to get linked models data

```
$posts = $this->Post->find('all')->contain(['User']);

$this->set('posts', $posts);
```

You will get User object with each post record which you can use to get user name, you do not need to write a separate query to fetch the user name.